# How to subscribe to merged infinite flowables?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a couple of infinite Flowables (getting data from BlockingQueues). I merge them and subscribe with my custom subscriber. I don't understand why I get messages only from a single input Flowable.

Here is my code:

```java
<T> void example() {
    List<BlockingQueue<T>> queues = createQueues();

    List<Flowable<T>> allFlowables = queues.stream()
            .map(this::createFlowable)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    FlowableScan.merge(allFlowables)
            .subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<T>() {

                @Override
                protected void onStart() {
                    System.out.println("Start!");
                    request(1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(T message) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                    request(1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    System.out.println("Done!");
                }
            });
}

<T> Flowable<T> createFlowable(BlockingQueue<T> queue) {
    return Flowable.generate(emitter -> {
        T msg = takeFromQueue(q); // blocking
        emitter.onNext(msg);
    });
}
```

What am I missing that I see messages from a single queue only?
I've tried with Schedulers, but it didn't help.
How to fix the above code to consume from all input queues?

Comment: Because you are blocking the only thread servicing all sources by the first queue. You have to introduce asynchrony such as applying `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` in `createFlowable`.

Comment: @akarnokd Exactly, I found the answer in this article:
https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/chaining-multiple-sources-with-rxjava-20eb6850e5d9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are blocking the only thread servicing all sources by the first queue. You have to introduce asynchrony such as applying `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` in `createFlowable`.

```java
<T> Flowable<T> createFlowable(BlockingQueue<T> queue) {
    return Flowable.generate(emitter -> {
        T msg = takeFromQueue(q); // blocking
        emitter.onNext(msg);
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); // <----------------------------------
}
```

Comment: Here is a nice article explaining multithreading in RxJava:
https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2016/02/29/rxjava-part-3-multithreading/